# Errors canceling AsyncTask "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method cancel(boolean) from the type AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Void>"

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I am trying to make it so that when the user pushes a button than it cancels the Asynk task and then finishes the activity but i keep getting errors with the "MyAsyncTask.cancel(true);" if there is additional info you need please tell me.

here is what I got,

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{
                boolean DoingSomething;
                int progress_status;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {

                    super.onPreExecute();
                    Log.v("UpGradeRep", "started");
                     DoingSomething = true;
                     UpGradeRep.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     UpGradeRepDis.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                             "started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    // progress_status  =   0;  
                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                     while (!isCancelled()) {

                         while(DoUpCount==true){

                        progress_status += 1;
                           publishProgress(progress_status);
                        SystemClock.sleep(200);

                                if(isCancelled()){
                                    break;
                                }
                        }

                   }  
                    return null;
                }
                int UpGradRepcounter = 0;
                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                    super.onProgressUpdate(values);


                    UpGradRepcounter++;

                    DevUpCountDis.setText(" "+UpGradRepcounter);
                    Money = Money +inc;
                    MoneyDis.setText("$"+Money);


                }

                @Override
                protected void onCancelled() {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);



                    DoUpCount=false;
                    DoingSomething = false;
                    Log.v("UpGradeRep", "Done");
                }

            }
```

here's what i do when i am trying to close it

```
Statistics.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MyAsyncTask.cancel(true);
          //^^^^Right here is where it tells me "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method cancel(boolean) from the type AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Void>"
            Intent GoToStatistics = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),statistics.class);
            GoToStatistics.putExtra("LittleHelper", LittleHelper);
            startActivity(GoToStatistics);

            finish();
            }
        });
```

so thats the code i set up to do what i whant and it dose good but when i leave it gives a frame drop warning in my Logcat so i was ausuming that im not closeing it properly

im starting it like this
so when the user pushes the button than it starts it

```
UpGradeRep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (Money>=upGM2) {
                LittleHelper=true;
                DoUpCount=true;
                Log.v("DoUpCount"," "+DoUpCount);
                (new MyAsyncTask()).execute();
            }else{
                Error.setText("you need more money.");
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: How are you starting your AsyncTask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to call a metod over a non-static object within a static context (the `onClick()`) event. Basically what that error is telling you is that you must make your `AsyncTask` object static in order to be able to call the `cancel()` method over it.

This is as "easy" as declaring your `AsyncTask` as `static`, but that could generate some other compilation errors over your `AsyncTask` object, and you'll have to be very thorough to avoid possible memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The method [cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)) (in class `AsyncTask`) is not a `static` method and you're calling it with the class name (the way static methods are invoked).

You should use the instance of `MyAsyncTask` to call (this):

```
this.cancel(true);
```

Comment: `cancel(boolean)` is a method of `AsyncTask`, AFAIK.